# Why is the subscript $f$ used to refer to properties relating to that of saturated liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, notation, phase-diagram

In the formula for calculating [Vapour Quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_quality), the properties relating to the saturated liquid have a subscript $f$. The properties relating to that of saturated gas have a subscript $g$. I understand why we have a $g$; I initially thought $f$ refers to the fluid, but then I realised both gas and liquids are fluids.
Though knowing it wouldn't make much of a change, I just like things to be meaningful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscripts originated from German:

*f* for flüssigkeit (liquid), and
*g* for gas (gas).

Comment: A calqued version of this is also why the latent heat to melt a solid is called "latent heat of fusion."